# Asymptotics of transitive finite group actions

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, asymptotics, group-actions

Given a finite group $G$, define the embedding number $\phi(G)$ to be the minimum natural number $N$ such that $G$ embeds in $S_N$.

For a fixed cardinality $n$, write $\widetilde{E}(n)$ for the average embedding number of $G$ as $G$ ranges over isomorphism classes of groups of order $n$, and write $E(n)$ for the slightly more natural
$$
\sum_{\#G = n} \frac{\phi(G)}{\#\text{Aut}(G)} \bigg/\sum_{\#G = n} \frac{1}{\#\text{Aut}(G)} .
$$

Is anything known about the asymptotics of $E(n)$ or $\widetilde{E}(n)$? What if we restrict $n$ to ranging over powers of a fixed prime (or just $2$)?

Comment: It seems very unlikely that anything significant is known about this, partly because we don't know for sure what typical groups look like. It is conjectured that aymptotically almost all finite groups are $2$-groups of class $2$ and exponent $4$, with a few other properties, but that remains a conjecture.